# Using wildcards in an xpath

Tags: java, xpath, wildcard, xpath-2.0

I have some text like this: "Viewing 101-200 of 244".  I would like to find this with an xpath.

Right now I use this:

`//*[contains(text(),'Viewing') and contains(text(),'of')]` which is all very well and good but could potentially match other patterns.  What I would like to do is something like in a regular expression as in the following:

`//*[contains(text(),'Viewing [0-9]+ of [0-9]+')]`

But I can't figure out how to use wild cards as above.  Is there any way to do this?  My guess is no?

Comment: what version of XPath does your tooling support?

Comment: A common way of avoiding this is to get the text from the element via normal xpath and let the calling application / test worry about patterns. Maybe this is in the header of a results table, so you might use (in java/c#-like pseudo code) `var results[] = GetTextFromElements(GetElementsByXpath("//table/thead/tr/td"));` then do your pattern matching where it's easier and more understandable.

Comment: Since we started using Web Center, the id's are long, crazy random names so I cannot really use:

//*[@id="pt1:r1:0:grppcr6:0:pt2:j_id__ctru5pc8"]/div

Comment: How do I verify my xpath version?

Comment: Doesn't have to be an id. Relative locators can be useful. Like `//table[1]/thead/tr/td[2]`.